# Ingres nested query

Tags: nested, ingres

I try this:

```
select fielda from tableA A
left join (select
fieldB
from tableB
)  B where A.fielda = B.fieldB
```

I have this error :

Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'exécution de la requête.
ERROR [42500] [CA][Ingres ODBC Driver][Ingres]Table 'select' does not exist or is not owned by you.

---

INFORMATIONS SUPPLÉMENTAIRES :

ERROR [42500] [CA][Ingres ODBC Driver][Ingres]Table 'select' does not exist or is not owned by you. (CAIIOD35.DLL)

How can I do?

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would use ON rather than WHERE following the subselect.

```
SELECT a.fielda from tableA a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT fieldB
  FROM tableB
)  b ON b.fielda = b.fieldB
```